# remove() elements after clone() in setInterval doesn't work at all

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `setInterval` function where after click on document, It clones squares one by one in two columns. When the scrollbar appears, the first row of two squares are removed from the DOM. But, the problem is that the squares removed from start are getting created again.

To see this clearly, please click the square when is created, it will add a text with number i++.

http://jsfiddle.net/kdkx1rnh/1/

You will see after square number 15 no more fresh squares.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Here's my Jquery code:

```
var i = 0;
var running = false
$(document).click(function(){
    if(running){
        return;
    }
    running = true;
var endless = setInterval(function(){

var random = Math.floor(2 * Math.random());
var math = (random == 1)? 0 : 1;

$(".square").first().clone().addClass('number'+math).fadeIn().appendTo('#container').on('mousedown',function(){
    if(math<1){
        $(this).text('even'+i).unbind('mousedown');
    } else {
        $(this).text('odd'+i).unbind('mousedown')
    }i++;});
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop:'+=70'},1000,'linear')},1000);

$(window).on('scroll',function(){
if($(".square:first").offset().top + $(".square:first").height() < $(window).scrollTop()){
    $(".square:first").remove()}
});
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone also copies the text.  If you change the text after you clone, instead of when you click on a square, you will see that there are no repetitions.

```
    $(".square").first().clone().addClass('number' + math).fadeIn().appendTo('#container').text((math < 1) ? 'even' + i : 'odd' + i);
i++;
```

instead of

```
$(".square").first().clone().addClass('number'+math).fadeIn().appendTo('#container').on('mousedown',function(){ ... }
```

Comment: it works. Now i must settle this to fire on mousedown like in my original post. Really thank you for pinpointing the problem.